# Creating executable file with pip install command on MacOS

Tags: macos, shell, command-line, terminal

I'm both new here and with MacOS and coding.
I know in windows I can create bash file to have an executable command in cmd. I've researched and discovered I can use similar file with MacOS (shell files) but I'm struggling to understand how to make one. I've tried different route:

As first thing I've tried creating a file in txt editor with this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
pip3 install pgzero
echo Installing Pygame Zero
```

Using later 'chmod 700 Filename' in terminal. It did not worked

I then tried with Apple Scrip, with a code like:

```
tell application "Terminal"
activate
do script "pip3 install pgzero"
do script "echo Installing Pygame Zero"
end tell
```

and it kinda worked, but it wasn't an executable

Then I tried with another approach found on google:

```
echo '#!/bin/bash
pip3 install pgzero
echo Installing PyGame Zero'> ~/Desktop/PygameInstaller.command

chmod 740> ~/Desktop/PygameInstaller.command
```

and it still didn't worked D:
Can someone land a bit of help? I'm starting feeling lost q,q
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In terms of what you want in your shell script, your first attempt is probably close to what you want but the `echo` should precede the `pip3` command. I guess if you change the verb from `Installing` to `Installed`, then you could leave it where it is.

```
$ cat <<EOF > ~/Desktop/PygameInstaller.command
#!/bin/bash
echo Installing Pygame Zero
pip3 install pgzero
EOF
$ chmod 700 ~/Desktop/PygameInstaller.command
```

The permissions you assign to the script and the script's location depend on who you want to grant execution. If it's only you, then your desktop and 700 should be fine.

Now, if you want to execute the script from a command line like what you would see if you opened an instance of `Terminal.app`, then you have options.

If you want to fully specify the command, then you would type this (showing prompt which you would not type):

```
$ ~/Desktop/PygameInstaller.command
```

If you want to specify only the name of the script, then you would type this after adding `~/Desktop` to your `PATH`:

```
$ PATH="$HOME/Desktop:$PATH"
$ PygameInstaller.command
```

If you prefer to type only `PygameInstaller`, then don't put the code in a file named `PygameInstaller.command`. Instead, you put the code in a file called simply `PygameInstaller`.

If you need the script to be executable by everyone, then put it in `/usr/local/bin` because most people will either have that in their `PATH` or have no political problem doing so. But you'll have to use the `sudo` command to elevate your privileges to accomplish that task.

If, however, you want to have that script be treated like any other app that you can launch with a double-click, then you have significantly more [work](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/224394/how-to-make-a-mac-os-x-app-with-a-shell-script) to do.

Comment: Thank you, Jeff! Your suggestion and link were super useful.
I didn't know I should specific .command, now the first attempt worked q,q
Is this extension that let shell file to be auto-executable in Terminal?

Also another newbie question:
If a friend of mine download a whole folder with PygameInstaller.command inside and run it, would it work? Or chmod 700 ~/FolderName/PygameInstaller.command would still be needed? Or should I use sudo, as you suggested?

Super thank you!